# using paypal sandbox with socialengine

Tags: paypal-sandbox, socialengine

Has anyone used Paypal sandbox with socialengine to test subscriptions?  I have looked at the code and can see where the developers have messed around with the sandbox, but i also see notes that it doesnt work.

I really would like to test my page with sandbox before releasing it, so any help or information would be welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by talking to a developer turns out that all you have to do is set the test_mode column in the engine4_payment_gateways database table to 1 and then it defaults to sandbox.

Comment: Can you explain here how you have been tested Paypal gateway in socialengine ?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable "Testing" payment gateway manually in `engine4_payment_gateways` by setting `enabled` to `1`. Then Default payment gateway's button will appear during subscription process.